# Receiving malformed JSON with parenthesis on top layer

Tags: json, swift, api, swift3, swifty-json

```
[Data]: 10633 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    branded =     (
                {
            "brand_name" = "Pal's Sudden Service";
            "brand_name_item_name" = "Pal's Sudden Service Hotdog";
            "brand_type" = 1;
            "food_name" = Hotdog;
            "nf_calories" = 300;
            "nix_brand_id" = 58769799a5bb96105b8fb337;
            "nix_item_id" = c6402707666e81250cff44d4;
            photo =             {
                highres = "<null>";
                thumb = "https://d2eawub7utcl6.cloudfront.net/images/nix-apple-grey.png";
```

I am trying to parse this JSON data, but I am struggling. When I simply call, for example, `json["branded"]["brand_name"]`, I receive nothing.

**How do I get around the parenthesis on the top layer and get to the data?**

I am using SwiftyJSON to parse the data, which is why it is formatted like my example.

Comment: Debug: Is `json["branded"]`nil? if not, `json["branded"]` seems to be an array, not a dictionary. so `json["branded"][0]["brand_name"]`?

Comment: Thank you VERY much, I did not realize () was an array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `json` variable is what you are showing for `[RESULT]:` in your question then you first need to get the value of the `"SUCCESS"` key. Then you can get the value for the `"branded"` key. And that result is an array. Parentheses in JSON means array. Nothing is malformed here.

```
if let success = json["SUCCESS"] as? [String:Any] {
    if let branded = success["branded"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        for brand in branded {
            let brandName = brand["brand_name"] as! String
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is, casting from JSON to [String:Any] will always fail

Comment: I'm not casting `json`. I'm casting the value obtained from `json["SUCCESS"]`.